# .net core How to get json object using path in string variable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

How to get json object using path in string variable,This is the JSON Schema data structure string stored in my database,I tried to convert to json data structure but it didn't work,I want to convert such a string data structure into a json object.

```
string json = $@"{{
            ""xcollapse.id"":""xcollapse"",
            ""xcollapse.el"":202,
            ""xcollapse.cols.props.cn"":""title"",
            ""xcollapse.cols.props.desc"":"""",
            ""xcollapse.cols.props.visible"":-1,
            ""xcollapse.cols.children.id"":""f272681"",
            ""xcollapse.cols.children.el"":200,
            ""xcollapse.cols.children.props"":""{{}}""
        }}";

var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

var result = jObj.ToString();
```

I would like to get the following results.

```
  {
  "xcollapse": {
    "id": "xcollapse",
    "el": "202",
    "cols": [
      {
        "props": {
          "cn": "title",
          "desc": "",
          "visible": "-1"
        },
        "children": {
          "id": "title",
          "el": "",
          "props": [
            {}
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The complete data structure in the database looks like this,I now need to convert to json objects to return to the front end.

```
    {
    "xcollapse.id":"xcollapse",
    "xcollapse.el":202,
    "xcollapse.props":{

    },
    "xcollapse.styles.visible":-1,
    "xcollapse.cols.deletable":false,
    "xcollapse.cols.props.cn":"title",
    "xcollapse.cols.props.desc":"",
    "xcollapse.cols.props.visible":-1,
    "xcollapse.cols.styles":null,
    "xcollapse.cols.children.id":"f272681",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.el":200,
    "xcollapse.cols.children.props":{

    },
    "xcollapse.cols.children.styles.visible":-1,
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.deletable":false,
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.props.visible":-1,
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.styles.span":8,
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.id":"fname",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.el":100,
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.ek":"fbillhead",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.cn":"title",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.group":"",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.fn":"fname",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.pn":"fname",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.desc":"",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.must":"0",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.visible":-1,
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.len":"100",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.lock":"0",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.copy":"1",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.defval":"",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.canchange":"0",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.xlsin":"1",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.acl":"1",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.sbm":"0",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.notrace":"1",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.apipn":"sourceType",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.ctlfk":"",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.editmode":"0",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.props.xsslv":"0",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.styles.align":"left",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.styles.width":"",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.styles.row":2,
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.cols":{},
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.deletable":true,
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.pid":"",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.children.seq":1,
    "xcollapse.cols.children.cols.seq":1,
    "xcollapse.cols.children.deletable":true,
    "xcollapse.cols.children.pid":"",
    "xcollapse.cols.children.seq":1,
    "xcollapse.cols.seq":1,
    "xcollapse.deletable":true,
    "xcollapse.pid":"",
    "xcollapse.seq":1,
}
```

Comment: Create a class for format A. Create a class for Format B. Deserialize into class A, map the data to class B then serialize class B. Done.

Comment: System.Text.Json doesn't support JSON Path or anything similar out of the box. There are libraries that do, for example [the JSON Everything packages](https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything)

Comment: BTW what you posted here is neither JSON Path nor JSON Schema. What's the actual question?

Comment: Whats your main json object looks like please include that within your question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  I have updated the question,I just want to convert a data path variable to a json object.

Comment: What do you mean "data path" then? What you posted looks like some custom flattened notation. While `"xcollapse.styles.visible"` is a valid attribute name, only your application would consider `"xcollapse.styles.visible"` to mean `Property Visible of object Style under XCollapse`.

Comment: `The complete data structure in the database looks like this` relational databases generally don't store JSON objects and document databases don't store flattened data. Is that some string actually stored in the database? Or produced by a `FOR JSON` clause? If that's generated by a SQL query it's better to modify the query to return objects or unflattened JSON

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Because of some special business scenarios I need to flatten the storage data storage and then take out the time to convert to json